# Shuffling columns in a delimited csv file

Tags: csv, perl, unix, awk, sed

I have a csv file:

```
$ cat test.csv

3424234,123544,263872387,99999,999, "", "", "", ""
```

I would like to exchange the values of the first and second columns for other random numeric values.

I've been trying to use awk, and so far I've managed to replace the entire line.

```
$ awk '{$1 = shuf -i 10000000000-99999999999 -n 1; print}' test.csv > suffled.csv
$ cat suffled.csv
0-899999999991
```

How would be the best way to do this treatment?

Comment: your terminology is confusing (at least for me). Please edit  your question to show a required sample output given your sample input. If I understand your intent correctly, I think you might ask "How do I substitute  values of the first and second columns for other random numeric values.?". Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk is not shell so you can't just call UNIX tools from it like you can from shell. In awk this:

```
$1 = shuf -i 10000000000-99999999999 -n 1
```

is equivalent to one of these or similar (I cant be bothered figuring out exactly how awk would parse it):

```
$1 = 0 -0 10000000000-99999999999 -0 1
$1 = 0 -0 ""-99999999999 -0 ""
```

since `shuf`, `i`, and `n` are unset awk variables with the value zero-or-null.

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; srand()} {$1=rand(); $2=rand()} 1' file
0.414006,0.899138,263872387,99999,999, "", "", "", ""
```

or maybe this?

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; srand()} {$1=r(); $2=r()} 1;
    function r(){return int(10000000000+rand()*(99999999999-10000000000+1))}' file
14241542683,61756440367,263872387,99999,999, "", "", "", ""
```

Comment: His response was just incredible, it was exactly what I wanted, but I was not getting it. Thanks!